# How can I receive a notification when the Action Button on the Microsoft Band is pressed?

Tags: microsoft-band

I can create a Band tile with a text button and receive notifications if that text button is pressed. But I really would like to use the Action hardware Button on my Microsoft Band. How can I receive a notification when the Action Button on the Microsoft Band is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Nothing in the SDKs I've seen lets you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not supported by the official SDK.

But some 3rd party apps have managed to use the button by using raw Bluetooth, but you would have to reverse-engineer the protocol used by the Band.